# LaTeX font error with TeX Live 2013

Tags: mactex

I use MacTeX and I recently changed my hard drive and upgraded to TeX Live 2013. I have a style file that I need to use for my thesis. It used to typeset fine, and when I upgraded, it stopped compiling and produces the following error:

```
Hi
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./thesis.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9f> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/report.cls
Document Class: report 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo))
(./smu_thesis.sty
kpathsea: Running mktextfm rpcrr
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input rpcrr
This is METAFONT, Version 2.718281 (TeX Live 2013)

kpathsea: Running mktexmf rpcrr

! I can't find file `rpcrr'.
<*> ...e:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input rpcrr

Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<*> ...e:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input rpcrr

Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: rpcrr.log: No such file or directory
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input rpcrr' failed to make rpcrr.tfm.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.


./smu_thesis.sty:948: Font \pf=rpcrr at 11.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file 
not found.
l.948 \font\pf=rpcrr at 11pt

? 
Process aborted
```

I know it has to do with a missing font and I checked for the location of the file `rpcrr*` in the old system and made sure it's present in the new system in following locations:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/cspsfonts-adobe/courier/rpcrro.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/cspsfonts-adobe/courier/rpcrr.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/courier/rpcrro.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/courier/rpcrr.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex4ht/ht-fonts/alias/adobe/courier/rpcrro.htf
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex4ht/ht-fonts/alias/adobe/courier/rpcrr.htf
```

Still, the thesis just won't typeset. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! The errors you report suggest that one or more `.map` files may be missing. Which `.map` files related to the `rpccr` font metric files are on your old computer?

Comment: I couldn't find any .map files associated with rpcrr font in my old computer. I did a search for all files with mdfind command - rpcrr

Comment: When you say that you "made sure" the files are present in the new system, what did you do exactly? I ask because none of those tfm files are included in my installation of TeX Live 2013. I only have the htf files. If you copied them over, that's not the right place to put them and there is more to it than that. On the other hand, if they already existed maybe there's something special about what MacTeX installs.

Comment: I am pretty sure those files are no longer included in TeX Live because the support for these fonts has changed. However, the fonts are still there. Can a Minimal Working Example demonstrating the code you are using the load the fonts and the problem? (Obviously it will not actually be a Working example in this case.) It is hard to say how best to adjust to the update without knowing what you have at the moment. I'm guessing you are using these fonts in a rather non-standard way.

Comment: Here is a simple example: the main file is:

\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{myStyleFile}

\begin{document}
test
\end{document} %------------------------------------------------------
and style file is:
\font\pf=rpcrr at 11pt
\font\spf=rpcrr at 11pt